# Installed client versus web application

Tags: web-applications, client-server, javafx

We're trying to decide on developing an internal-only support application as either:

- An installed client (probably Java with a JavaFX UI)
- A web application

The considerations are:

1. Must be able to be developed and deploy quickly by a small team
2. Must be able to be modified quickly as new business requirements are added
3. There must be a separate server-side layer. This server will have access to the data, and must deliver information to the client securely over the internet.
4. Deployment/distribution of 'client' application is not a concern (the usual "distribution is a problem" concern of client applications isn't an issue)

It seems obvious that a deployed client application meets these needs better than a web application (particularly around points #1 and #2...we wouldn't need web UI experts, no wrangling with the back button, etc), but that makes me worried that I'm missing some obvious concern.

Why *wouldn't* you choose a deployed-client application in this situation?

Comment: How would a web application not meet needs 1 OR 2 very well. A web app can be updated almost instantaneously. I would think with the number of supporting plugins and existing applications, a small team could develop faster than a installed client. Also, you don't have to worry about platform.

Comment: Leeish, thanks for the comment. Web adds the overhead of the dev team knowing/writing HTTP, CSS, Javascript, Javascript libraries, browser functionality variations. Platform independence isn't a big consideration either way - making the client Java makes it run on Win and Apple desktop (which is all we need).

Comment: I agree with rz-requilel, if you team doesn't know web, then why waste the resources to develop. But if they know both, web is just a much more flexible solution. So many businesses are going SOS for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your clients **status**, *needs* and what *expertise* your team can offer. If you already have a team that is capable to develop a java-based client then I don't understand why you're asking, but alright.

I would not choose the deployed-client application, because:

- A web application can be used from *anywhere*
- Data transferring is quicker
- No issues with incorrectly displayed or corrupted data
- With some good research possible to develop a crossbrowser compatible application
- Less bandwith usage for your company (depending how many clients you have, obviously)
- Easier to update

I personally would need more information to provide a better answer.